# Segmented area between circles

Tags: geometry, curvature

The following is a geometry problem that I came across with in the course of a research project.

Consider a ray starting at some initial point $t$. Place point $s_1$ at distance $r$ from $t$ on the ray and draw a circle centered at $s_1$ that passes through $t$. Likewise, centered at $t$, an arc with radius $r$ goes through $s_1$. Let $\mathcal{A_1}$ be the area enclosed between the intersecting arcs.

Next, arbitrarily place another point somewhere on the free end of the ray and call it $s_2$ such that $|s_1 - t| < |s_2 - t|$, where $|.|$ denotes the Euclidean distance. A circle with radius $r$ is centered at $s_2$ and another arc centered at $t$ goes through $s_2$. The area enclosed between these intersecting arcs we call $\mathcal{A}_2$. It is easy to show that $\mathcal{A}_1 < \mathcal{A}_2 < \lim_{|s_2 - t| \to \infty} \mathcal{A}_2 = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2$.

Now, assume that we mark the segments of the ray within the enclosed areas in the middle and arcs centered at $t$ pass through the marks segmenting $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$. We call these segmented areas $\mathcal{A}_{11}$ and $\mathcal{A}_{12}$ and $\mathcal{A}_{21}$ and $\mathcal{A}_{22}$ as depicted below (dashed lines are the arcs centered at $t$).

[image]

**Question:** How does $\mathcal{A}_{22}$ change as $s_2$ gets farther from $t$? (i.e., does it increase or decrease?) What can we say about $\mathcal{A}_{22}$ in comparison with $\mathcal{A}_{12}$?

Any idea or comment is much appreciated.

EDIT: The question has been edited in a way that makes the comments incomprehensible. Please see the edit history if you want to make sense of the comments.

EDIT: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100204/segmented-area-between-circles) is the link to the same question at [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net)

Comment: Do you have numeric evidence that $A_{12}>A_{22}$. Intuitively, I would reason: If we move $s_1$ a bit farther right, $A_{11}$ would shrink to a point and $A_{12}$ would be a circle of radius $\frac r2$, whose area is definitely less than that of $A_{22}$. It looks unintuitive to me that the area of the $A_{\cdot 2}$ would be increasing from $s_2$ to $s_1$ only suddenly decrease to the right of $s_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @HenningMakholm. The fact is that $s_1$ is a fixed point at distance $r$ from $t$ and $s_2$ is the only point that we arbitrarily choose. In other words, we are not allowed to move $s_1$.

Regarding your question on the numerical evidence, I should say no. In fact, I do not know any way to numerically evaluate these regions. Whatever I said is just based on my intuition and of course I am not sure of its correctness.

Comment: Who says we're not allowed to imagine $s_1$ being somewhere else? But if that bothers you, just put an $s_0$ half a unit to the right of $s_1$ instead, and consider how unlikely it seems that $A_{02}<A_{22}<A_{12}$.

Comment: Well, if you want to move $s_1$ anywhere, you are also changing the radius $r$. In other words, the circle centered at $s_1$ must always pass through $t$. This is, in fact, part of the problem definition.

Comment: Again, if that gives you problems, just imagine that the point midways between the original $s_1$ and $t$ is called some thing else than $s_1$. I suggested $s_0$, but you may also call is $s_7$ or $q$.

Comment: If you let $s_2\to\infty$, then it's easy to calculate $A_{21}$ as it's a third of the circle minus a 120-30-30 triangle with short side $r$. Then you can get $A_{22}$. So if you can find a way to calculat, or estimate, $A_{11}$, then you can get $A_{12}$ (since $A_1$ is easy), and compare.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I am not concerned with naming. My point is that by moving $s_1$ to the right, you also shrink radius $r$. Note that both circles centered at $s_1$ and $s_2$ have the same radius $r$. What you are trying to do by moving $s_1$ to the right is similar to down scaling the picture and does not change the problem.

Comment: Well, freaking _don't move it_, then. Leave $s_1$ exactly where it is, and instead put a _new_ point to the right of $s_1$, and draw the same circles centered at $t$ that you do for $s_1$ and $s_2$, just intersecting your _new_ point instead of the $s_1$ and $s_2$. The conclusion is exactly the same no matter how you describe the operation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I think I am not getting you quite clearly. With that _new_ point, say $s_0$, are we getting rid of $A_{01}$? Would that _new_ circle centered at $s_0$ contain only $A_{02}$ with which we compare $A_{12}$ and $A_{22}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure though, given that $A_{22} < A_{12}$ when $s_2 \to \infty$, can we claim that $A_{22} < A_{12}$ for any $s_2$ between $s_1$ and $\infty$?

Comment: Before you decide on the implications, better check the facts. If $A_{22}\gt A_{12}$ as $s_2\to\infty$, then that will prove that there is some finite place where $A_{22}\gt A_{12}$. In other words, this is an attempt to prove that the conjecture is *wrong*.

Comment: Ali, please edit in a link to the identical question posted at MathOverflow, and please edit in a link to this question over there.

Comment: @Ali: Yes, with the new point being put at a distance $\frac R2$ from $T$, $A_{01}$ has shrunk to a circle of radius $0$, so $A_{02}$ is the entire circle of radios $\frac R2$.

Answer (score 3):

The shape of $A_1$ is always the same, so we can calculate its area as the sum of two [circular segments](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html): $A_1 = r^2(2\pi/3 - \sqrt{3}/2)$.

Let's first let $t$ be the origin (why the hell would you name the origin of a ray $t$?!). Let's set $r=1$, keeping in mind all areas will be scaled by $r^2$ later.
The coordinates of the vertices of $A_{11}$ are $(1/8,\pm \sqrt{15}/8)$, and the subtended angles are $2\tan^{-1} \sqrt{15}$ and $2\tan^{-1} \sqrt{15}/7$.
This then gives $A_{11} \approx 0.350767 (r^2)$, $A_{1} \approx 1.22837$, and $A_{12} \approx 0.877603$.
Note that all these numbers can be made precise; they're just huge ugly expressions, and remember they are multiplied by $r^2$.

Now let $s_2$ be located at coordinates $(R,0)$ where $R > 1$ according to our assumptions.
By similar reasoning, the vertices of $A_2$ are $(\frac{2R^2-1}{2R},\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4R^2}})$.
Similarly now, we can compute $A_{22}$. The expression for $A_{22}/A_{12}$ is horrendously large, so I will just have Mathematica plot it as a function of $R$:

[image]

The limit according to Mathematica is $1.09003$.

Edit: I have corrected a number of mistakes. Now, the area ratio is always greater than unity for $R>1$.

Comment: I should just like to add that numerically evaluating the areas is extremely simple as the sum of circular segments, and can even be done in a numerically robust way when the segments are thin slivers. For C code, see the function CircularSectorArea in [this file](https://github.com/victorliu/S4/blob/master/src/pattern/intersection.c)

Comment: Nice. Is it true that $A_{22}\gt A_{12}$ for all values of $R$?

Comment: No. The plot clearly shows that it crosses over the area of $A_{12}$. Mathematica says this happens around $R=9.23574$.

Comment: Thanks. The plot doesn't show this, unless you put in a horizontal line, labeled, at $A_{12}$ and the plot extends below this line.

Comment: @VictorLiu: How can that be? If we set $R=1$, then $A_{22}$ and $A_{12}$ coincide. Are there _two_ $R$ values that give the same $A_{22}$ area?

Comment: @Henning Makholm: You are indeed correct; I made a number of mistakes. I have correct them now.

Comment: Thanks, @Victor. I do not believe if it is easy at all to formally prove that $A_{22}$ grows with distance to $t$. I think numerical evaluation of the regions (like what you did in your answer) is the best way to approach the problem. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Mathematica; so, I am trying to implement some code in MATLAB. I will update the post if I come up with more interesting results.